# Is there any software that can help me reinstall software after fresh install

Tags: linux, software-installation

Every now and then I need to reinstall Linux system (mainly Ubuntu based distros). The process of reinstalling every piece of software I need is really boring and time consuming. Is there any software that can help me out? For Windows there is Ninite, is there something else for Linux?

Edit: Thanks for all the answers! I went with Ansible and it is an amazing tool.

Comment: Why do you need to reinstall your system so often?

Comment: As @Martin have answered, using the tools that comes with your Ubuntu or Debian (dpkg and apt) work really well, as they are part of your system (you don't have to install them, they are already there). You don't need to deal with more complicated tools as Ansible and Nix - although it is a good idea to learn about them.

Comment: Also, thank you for the Ninite tip! I didn't know about it! Neat!

Comment: Can you get away with something as simple as a bash script containing a single command: "sudo apt install X Y Z" ?

Comment: @Henrique If Martin already have answered the question, why did you then ignore the text that says _"Avoid answering questions in comments."_? It's there for a reason.

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit verbose. My intention was to encourage the OP to go and learn about Ansible, even if it's too much for what he wants to do. It may save his skin later in life. But you are right, I tend to talk too much. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Ansible is an open-source software provisioning, configuration management, and application-deployment tool. It runs on many Unix-like systems, and can configure both Unix-like systems as well as Microsoft Windows. It includes its own declarative language to describe system configuration

(From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible_(software)).) [Homepage (Github)](https://github.com/ansible/ansible).

There are several others in the same category. Reading about [ansible](/questions/tagged/ansible) should give you vocabulary to search for the others, and compare, if needed. [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) is a newer contender. Some say "more complex, but maybe just right.". [chef](/questions/tagged/chef) is also on the scene.

Ansible example for hostname `myhost`, module `apt` (replace with `yum` or whatever):

```
ansible -K -i myhost, -m apt -a "name=tcpdump,tmux state=present" --become myhost
```

The list "tcpdump,tmux" can be extended with commas. (The fact, that the hostname `myhost` is twice in the command-line, because we are not using a fixed host inventory list, but an ad-hoc one, with the trailing comma.)

This only scratches the surface, [Ansible has an extensive module collection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/index_module.html).

Comment: Using a tool like ansible also helps with maintaining configuration of installed applications.

Comment: Ansible is a great idea, though you can (and probably should) go a lot farther with it. I have a 319-line playbook plus some ancillary files and templates that installs and configures my local laptop from a fresh OS installation. When I change something, I change the playbook and run it. When I have to reinstall the OS, I then rerun the playbook and everything is restored (unless I forgot something, which does happen).

Comment: Ansible is to Nix what Bash is to Haskell. If you have the time and energy to learn Nix it is vastly superior to Ansible in several ways: reproducibility, actually being declarative rather than just a thin layer on top of shell commands, isolated versions (so you can install for example two versions of system software like Bash or Python at the same time). Nix takes about the same time to learn as Ansible, but is more abstract and has fewer limitations and surprises (this is after using Ansible for two years and Nix for about three months).

Comment: @l0b0: Nix is great but unless something has vastly changed in regards to what it is, it has nothing to do with using distro packages and is not a substitute or competitor for ansible. Rather it's a substitute for the whole Debian (and other distros) package system.

Comment: Other open-source alternatives to Ansible (agent-less => no dedicated central server required) include [Puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(company)#Puppet) (can be used in master/agent mode as well as standalone, has a large collection of powerful community-maintained modules), [Chef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chef_(software)), [Salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(software)) and [CFEngine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFEngine). [Compare on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software).

Answer (score 42):

### Save and restore all packages

On Debian/Ubuntu based systems you can dump the list of installed packages to a file

```
dpkg --get-selections > my_package_list.txt
```

and install them again by running

```
apt-cache dumpavail | sudo dpkg --merge-avail
sudo dpkg --set-selections < my_package_list.txt
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

The first line ensures `dpkg`'s database is up to date (nowadays most people use `apt` to install packages which maintains its own database), the second line imports your saved selections and the third command installs the selected packages. See the [Debian Administrator's Handbook](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.apt-get.en.html) for details.

In case you have installed packages from third-party repositories you need to add these repositories before following the above steps for restoring.

### Save and restore only explicitly installed packages

[Aptitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_(software)) automatically installs dependencies (e.g. a library required by an application). These packages are flagged as "automatic" and can be automatically removed when they aren't required anymore. In case you want to preserve these "automatic" flags we can't use `dpkg` since it doesn't track automatically installed packages. Instead we have to use the slightly more cryptic

```
LC_ALL=C aptitude search -F '%p %C' '~i!~M' > my_package_list.txt
```

This will search all packages that are installed (`~i`) and not (`!`) flagged automatic (`~M`). For each matching package the package name (`%p`) and the status (`%C`) will be printed (this mimics the output of `dpkg --get-selections`). `LC_ALL=C` ensures that all output is done in English without translation to a native language. Use the commands mentioned above for installing the packages from this list. Refer to the [aptitude user's manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/index.en.html) for details.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that, usually, `apt install` updates `dpkg`'s internal availability status info, so if you were to omit the `dpkg --merge-avail` step, it would tell you it doesn't know those packages despite them being in `apt`'s cache (since I assume `apt update` was run on the new system)?

Comment: `!~M` doesn't exclude packages installed during the original system installation. I.e. in addition to the manually installed packages, the resulting list of packages will include much longer list of "base" system packages. Potentially, this can bring "orphaned" packages onto a fresh machine.

Comment: @Trudy true, the presented solution is pretty simple. If you are planning to maintain packages over a long time I would recommend to look at Ansible, Chef, Puppet, Salt and friends.

Comment: @MartinKonrad, thanks for suggesting the alternatives. They are too complex for my needs though. I played a bit with `aptitude why`, and I wonder: if to assume that manually installed packages have no upward dependencies, then can we pipe output from your command to `aptitude why` and narrow down the list this way?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to install a bunch of packages a simple one-liner could do like:

```
sudo bash -c 'for package in "tmux" "htop" "gimp"; do apt install -y --no-upgrade "$package"; done'
```

The loop is not strictly necessary, but without it, if apt fails to find any of the programs in the list, it will fail to install any of the other packages. This can happen for example if you switch to a more recent version of your distro and older packages are not within the repos anymore. If you prefer all or nothing use

```
sudo apt install -y --no-upgrade tmux htop gimp
```

If you also want to save your configurations the search term would be "dotfiles". Thats what the configurations in Unix like systems are called since they mostly start with a ".".

A quick and dirty way to save those is just by copying all those configurations directory to your new system. A better way would be to place them under version control with tools like git. I use a combination of git, dotbot and hand written scripts to setup my system.

## Update

One point that is missing from the discussion so far is that `apt` is typically not the only package management system one needs for anything beyond the bare basics. 
Other package management tools might be `snap`, `pip`, `conda`, `cargo` and many more.
This is implicitly addressed in the answer by Alex Stragies. `Ansible` contains a vast ammount of modules including modules to manage packages apart from `apt` like `snap` and `pip`.
As my answer is focused on write-your-own-script I'd like to expand on that. 
A well tested framework such as `Ansible` should generally be prefered for most tasks, but self-written code gives an advantage in terms of flexibility in my eyes.

### Small example framework

I've written a small code in python which shall examplify how such a framework could look.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import re
import sys
import subprocess

def read_package_list(path):
    package_list=[]
    try:
        with open(os.path.realpath(path)) as f:
            for line in f:
                match = re.search(r'^(?!\s*$)(?!#)\w+',line)
                if match:
                    package_list.append(match.group(0))
            return package_list
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.message)
        print(e.args)
        sys.exit(1)    
    return package_list

def install_packages(command,package_list,err_log):
    try:
        with open(err_log,'w+') as f:
            for p in package_list:
                print('executing '+command+' '+str(p))
                out=subprocess.run(command+' '+p,shell=True,stderr=f)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.message)
        print(e.args)
        sys.exit(1)

def main():
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    package_list = read_package_list(args[1])
    err_log=os.path.realpath(args[2])
    install_packages(args[0],package_list,err_log)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The basic ingredients are a function to process a list of packages separated by newlines (`read_package_list`) and a function to execute the installer command in a shell (`install_packages`). 
Lines with only whitespace and lines starting with `#` are ignored when reading in the package list.
The `main` processes the arguments which can be given on the command line as `installer command`, `packagefile`, `errorlog`.

### What does that give me?

Well you can just use any installer command you like

```
./installerscript.py 'apt install --dry-run' myaptpackages.txt apt_err.log
./installerscript.py 'snap install' mysnaps.txt snap_err.log
./installerscript.py 'pip install --user' mypy.txt py_err.log
./installerscript.py 'git clone' repos.txt git_err.log
```

This might be helpful if one keeps a list of packages which should all be treated in the same way.
Once such a framework exist it is easy to improve on it.
One could, for example, customize the way the installation process is logged or customize the processing of the command line arguments.
Another aspect is that the script probably shouldn't execute each command as root (if run as root) as it currently does.

Comment: Silently ignoring error messages by doing a for loop seems hacky at best. If apt fails to find a package, I'd like to know of it. When installing a laptop/desktop I want to find a replacement or at least I know I will be missing a package, or for unattended deployments the automatic install should fail because the system environment changed and the script needs updating.

Comment: @Luc executing apt in a loop does not discard lines written to stderr. They will still be shown on the command line, although admittedly harder to find between the stdout output. One could add something like `2>errors.log` to get a basic form of error logging.

Answer (score 1):

If you install software from the command line, then doing

```
grep "^sudo apt install" ~/.bash_history > system-setup.sh
```

once the system setup is complete will provide you with a script, which (after some editing) can be reused to set up a freshly installed system next time you need it.

Comment: What if your history file doesn't go back till the beginning of time? What if you use apt-get sometimes? What if you used a visual front-end? What if you also want packages installed as part of an installation guide that used "apt update && apt install x"? I'm not sure this is a solution, especially 7 hours after Martin posted Debian's solution. That said, I do have a system-setup script myself where I put my favorite packages for different purposes (one base install, one for graphical environments, one with IDEs, one with WiFi tools if the system has WiFi, etc.), but that wasn't the question.

Comment: @Luc The OP presumably reinstalls the system regularly, so there's a good chance they will have everything still in history. Ideally this should be done right after the system setup is complete. Grepping for apt-get instead of apt is trivial.